本来なら in this sentence
The following is taken from the anime Konosuba!. The main character has just died while trying to save a girl from being run over by a tractor which would have stopped in time anyway. Once in the afterlife, a goddess explains to him the details of his futile death. I think this is a simplified (informal) third-conditional sentence.
あなたが突き飛ばさなければ (if you hadn't pushed her out of the way...) あの子はケガもしなかったんですけどね。あのトラクターは本来ならあの子の手前で止まったんです。
My question is: what is the meaning of 本来なら exactly? It looks like it should mean something like "by itelf / on its own", but it could also mean "in the first place" for all I know, which would be a rather different meaning....

本来 refers to a natural, inherent or original state of something, as opposed to its special or modified state. For example:

この場所は本来は森の中でしたが、ダムのせいで湖になりました。
This place was originally a forest, but it became a lake because of the dam.
今は怒っていますが、本来の彼は温厚なんです。
He is angry right now, but his true self is gentle and kind.
その問題が解決したことで、彼は本来の力を取り戻した。
He regained his original strength after the problem was resolved.

Possible translations of 本来なら include "under normal circumstances", "if nothing happened", "if everything went as expected", "ideally speaking", and "normally". It is used when there is some special circumstance.

通常、ポストは赤い。
Postboxes are normally red. (as a plain fact)
本来ならポストは赤い。
Normally, postboxes are supposed to be red (although this one is blue for some reason).
本来なら彼女が謝罪するべきだ。
Normally, she should be the one to apologize.
本来ならもう家についているはずなのに。
We're supposed to have arrived home by now...

In your case, 本来なら is used to present what would have naturally (or originally) happened if he hadn't pushed her. She's also suggesting that his pushing was unexpected and shouldn't have happened.

Thank you for the detailed answer and example sentences, I appreciate it.
